# Android: ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE with com.android.email

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I'm trying to send multiple attachments in an Intent to the Email app (not the Gmail app). I'm using:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[] { "sample@email.com" });
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"This is an email");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is the body");

File f1 = null;
File f2 = null;
try {
    f1 = new File("/sdcard/test");
    f2 = new File("/sdcard/test.1");
    FileWriter fw1 = new FileWriter(f1);
    FileWriter fw2 = new FileWriter(f2);
    fw1.write("this is some text");
    fw2.write("this is more text");
    fw1.close();
    fw2.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
uris.add(Uri.fromFile(f1));
uris.add(Uri.fromFile(f2));
emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uris);

startActivity(emailIntent);
```

When Gmail is used to handle the Intent, it comes up with both attachments showing, and everything works just fine. When the Email app is used instead, no attachments are added. When using a single Uri in EXTRA_STREAM, the single attachment works, but using an ArrayList does not. I've pieced together this code from other questions asked on here, but none of them resolve this issue. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

use

```
emailIntent.setType(" */ * ");
```

with no spaces

[see here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE) ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this is quite late, but your intent type is backwards. It should be

```
emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
```

not

```
emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
```

I'm surprised neither of the other answers pointed that out...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

> emailIntent.setType("plain/text");

use

> emailIntent.setType("application/octet-stream");

I don't know why, but it's working for me.